# Make TypeScript function accept Redux connected component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, redux

I've got a React Native project where I've got a `Screen` class, and `HomeScreen`, `MyProfileScreen` classes derived from it (I know, composition preferred over inheritance, but let's keep that argument somewhere else) (irrelevant parts redacted, but notice the `identifier` getter function, I'll come to that):

```
export default class Screen<P = {},S = {},SS = {}> extends Component<P,S,SS> {
    static get identifier(){
        return this.name;
    }     
}
```

Then, in my home screen and profile screen (which basically has the same structure with home screen):

```
export default class HomeScreen extends Screen<HomeScreenProps & HomeScreenDispatchProps>{
    [...]
}
```

Now, I'm writing a function where it accepts a class derived from `Screen`, and accessing its static getter `identifier`:

```
export default function wrapStackNavigator<T extends typeof Screen>(screen:T){
    return <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name={screen.identifier} component={screen}/>
    </Stack.Navigator>
}
```

So far so good, I can call `wrapStackNavigator` with any screen classes with no type errors. Now the problem begins. I want to make my screens connected components, so I go ahead and `connect` them to Redux as usual:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps, mergeProps)(HomeScreen)
```

At this point, calls `wrapStackNavigator` starts complaining about types not being compatible. I know the reason: `connect` returns a different type which wraps the original class, but I have no idea how to fix it. I've tried to change `wrapStackNavigator` to accept `ConnectedComponent` or `InferableComponentEnhancerWithProps` (which apparently `connect` returns) but no avail (or I've got the type arguments wrong).

How can I make `wrapStackNavigator` accept *either* a class derived from `Screen`, *or* a `connect`ed class derived from `Screen`, while still being able to access static properties of the passed derived `Screen` class, with no typing errors? (and please, no casting to `any`, I know that would "solve" it but I don't consider it a solution). I'm on TypeScript 3.6.3.

Comment: Would https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types somehow work where you do `<T extends typeof Screen>`?

Comment: @timotgl I've been trying to get it working but couldn't find a way.

Comment: Maybe post what you've tried? It should be a common use case to expect one or the other type.

Comment: Patient: It hurts when I do this.  Dr: don't use typescript.  Sorry, I just think the typescript Hype overvalues the benefit and underestimates the  cost.  Maybe use when publishing a lib, but not when building an app.

Comment: @MkeSpaGuy definitely need to disagree on this one. i can't imagine coding an app without proper strongly-typed support.